# Structural induction in Haskell (take n . map f) xs = (map f . take n) xs

Tags: haskell

How to show that for every function f and for every finite List xs following holds:
(take n . map f) xs = (map f . take n) xs

```
take :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
take 0 _ = []
take _ [] = []
take n (x:xs) = x : take (n-1) xs

map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map _ [] = []
map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs

(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
(.) f g x = f(g x)
```

Show for every step the used argument. How I actually start on such problems and whats the way to prove it generally. Would appreciate some help to get into this easier.

looked into my script but couldnt really grasp it

Comment: Start by proving `(take n . map f) [] = (map f . take n) []`. This is really just manually evaluating both expressions. If you get stuck, ask a question about exactly your problem. If not, show your proof of the empty-list case and ask about how to generalise it to nonempty lists.

Comment: For a start, you might want to show that it is true for empty lists. See  [proof by induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction).

Comment: To prove a property `p()` on all lists by induction, one has to first prove it on the empty list `p([])`, and then on non-empty lists `p(x:xs)` under the assumtion that `p(xs)` holds (the induction hypothesis). In your case, you need to first prove `(take n . map f) [] = (map f . take n) []`, and then prove `(take n . map f) (x:xs) = (map f . take n) (x:xs)` underthe assumption `(take n . map f) xs = (map f . take n) xs`. Try unraveling the definitions: what is `map f []`? What is `map f (x:xs)`? Maybe at some point you'll need to make two subcases: `n=0` or `n>0`.

Comment: `n = 0` : `(take 0 . map f) [] = (map f . take 0) []` as we have `take 0 xs = []` our equation becomes  `[] = []` In the case for n > 0 : `(take n . map f) [] = (map f . take n) []` we have  `take n [] = []` so both sides become [] again . I dont really know where to start when I need to show the general case

Comment: Here's a start: `(take n . map f) (x:xs) = take n (map f (x : xs)) = take n (f x : map f xs) = ??? = map f (take n (x:xs)) = (map f . take n) (x:xs)`. Can you finish it? Remember that at some point you need to apply the induction hypothesis.

Comment: Also, please write your proofs in the question and not in the comments here. That way you have more space so you can take smaller steps and add explanations for each step.

Answer (score 1):

I will follow the examples in **Thinking Functionally** by Richard Bird (Cambridge University Press, 2015, pp. 113 - 115).

> We have seen that every finite list is either the empty list `[]` or of the form `x:xs` where `xs` is a finite list. Hence, to prove that *P(xs)* holds for all finite lists *xs*, we can prove:
>
> 1. *P(*`[]`*)* holds;
> 2. For all `x` and for all finite lists `xs`, that *P(*`x:xs`*)* holds **assuming** *P(*`xs`) **does**. [emphasis mine]

The assumption mentioned in point two will be very important and referenced as "{induction}" in the proof.

First, let's lay out the equations for `map` and `take` with the references to be used in the proof.

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map f [] = []                      -- {map.1}
map f (x:xs) = f x : map f xs      -- {map.2}

take :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
take n [] = []                     -- {take.1}
take 0 xs = []                     -- {take.2}
take n (x:xs) = x : take (n-1) xs  -- {take.3}
```

**Proof:**

We want to prove *P(xs)* holds for all finite lists *xs* where our property, *P*, is `(take n . map f) xs == (map f . take n) xs`.

**Case `[]`**

```
(take n . map f) []               (map f . take n) []
= {map.1}                         = {take.1}
take n []                         map f []
= {take.1}                        = {map.1}
[]                                []
```

*P(*`[]`*)* holds.

**Case `x:xs`**

```
(take n . map f) (x:xs)           (map f . take n) (x:xs)
= {map.2}                         = {take.3}
take n (f x : map f xs)           map f (x : take (n-1) xs)
= {take.3}                        = {map.2}
f x : (take (n-1) (map f xs))     f x : (map f (take (n-1) xs))
= {composition}                   = {composition}
f x : ((take (n-1) . map f) xs)   f x : ((map f . take (n-1)) xs)
                                  = {induction}
                                  f x : ((take (n-1) . map f) xs)
```

*P(*`x:xs`*)* holds.

Q.E.D.

In my opinion, the tricky part is the "{induction}" step.  It is based on the very equivalence we are trying to prove.  This is based on the assumption that *P(*`xs`*)* holds, as in point two in the quotation from **Thinking Functionally** above.

All I can offer here is the advice that you convince yourself of the legitimacy of the assumption.  In "Case []" we show that P holds for an empty list, which is nevertheless an instance of xs.  In "Case (x:xs)" we show that the first item in the list is the same for both sides, therefore we, in effect, know that P holds for [x] as well -- another instance of xs. Having shown that P holds for [] and [x], the assumption is sound. Then proceeding to another item in the list can be intuited as simply reiterating what has already been established. At least this is how I understand it.